# Calling constructor super errors with 3 passed, 0 expected

Tags: dart, flutter

Background: I'm trying to inherit from AnimatedCrossFade to apply this patch https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/10243 as a subclass (rather than forking flutter).  I'm just learning dart/flutter, and honestly I thought that creating a cross-fade from a loading widget to a network image would have been a really simple thing to try first (it's not easy at all, `FadeInImage` doesn't crossfade nor does it take a widget [despite the design goal of nearly everything in flutter being a widget],`Image.network` does not have a `onDownloadCompleted` callback, and `AnimatedCrossFade` has the aforementioned bug with centering). Anyway...

Here's the code I'm calling:

```
class FixedCrossFade extends AnimatedCrossFade {
  const FixedCrossFade({
    Key key,
    @required firstChild,
    @required secondChild,
    firstCurve: Curves.linear,
    secondCurve: Curves.linear,
    sizeCurve: Curves.linear,
    alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
    @required crossFadeState,
    @required duration,
    layoutBuilder: AnimatedCrossFade.defaultLayoutBuilder,
  }) : super(
    key,
    firstChild,
    secondChild,
    firstCurve: firstCurve,
    secondCurve: secondCurve,
    alignment: alignment,
    crossFadeState: crossFadeState,
    duration: duration,
    layoutBuilder: layoutBuilder
    );
}
```

For reference, this is `AnimatedCrossFade`'s constructor:

```
const AnimatedCrossFade({
  Key key,
  @required this.firstChild,
  @required this.secondChild,
  this.firstCurve: Curves.linear,
  this.secondCurve: Curves.linear,
  this.sizeCurve: Curves.linear,
  this.alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
  @required this.crossFadeState,
  @required this.duration,
  this.layoutBuilder: defaultLayoutBuilder,
}) : assert(firstChild != null),
    assert(secondChild != null),
    assert(firstCurve != null),
    assert(secondCurve != null),
    assert(sizeCurve != null),
    assert(alignment != null),
    assert(crossFadeState != null),
    assert(duration != null),
    assert(layoutBuilder != null),
    super(key: key);
```

My `FixedCrossFade` class errors with:

```
error: line 33 pos 8: invalid arguments passed to super class constructor 'AnimatedCrossFade.': 3 passed, 0 expected
```

Where line number 33 corresponds to the line `}) : super(`

I'm not actually changing the constructor, I believe all I need to do is overrride `createState`, and completely reimplement the state object. Coming from a python / C++ background, I was quite surprised that extending `AnimatedCrossFade` without any changes causes an error:

```
class FixedCrossFade extends AnimatedCrossFade {}
...

No constructor 'FixedCrossFade' declared in class 'FixedCrossFade'
```

I'm very very new to dart and flutter, so this is probably a very simple mistake. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Ah ha! I solved my problem.  Those `@required` were throwing me off.  All variables in this constructor are named variables.  I need to name them in the super call. I'm still a bit confused why I need to explicitly define this constructor at all though...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you noticed, the super-constructor has only named parameters, but you are passing `key`, `firstChild` and `secondChild` without a name, so they are positional arguments. Change those to:

```dart
}) : super(
    key : key,
    firstChild: firstChild,
    secondChild: secondChild,
    firstCurve: firstCurve,
```

and the super-invocation will work.

You need to add a constructor because constructors are not inherited. They are not instance methods, they are rather more like static methods which are also not inherited. So, for your class to have any constructor, it needs to declare it, and then call a suitable generative super-constructor to create the superclass. It's, admittedly, annoying when all you do is forward arguments.

Comment: Thanks for the constructor explanation, that helps!